# How do I access one model from another which don't have direct relationship?

Tags: php, laravel

I have an User model. Each user has certain grades and each grade has certain students.

User and Grade models have one-to-many relationship. Grade and Student models have one-to-many relationship too. But, User and Student models don't have any relationship.

Once User is logged in, he should be able to search all students that belongs to the user.

Do I have to create relationship between these two models to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, a user has multiple students, so what I'd do is create a `one-to-many` relationship between them like this:

//User.php

```
public function students() 
{
  return $this->hasMany(Student::class);  
}
```

//Student.php

```
public function user() 
{
  return $this->belongsToOne(User::class);  
}
```

This would allow you to pick up a users students by doing: `$students = $user->students` *Note: I didn't use `()` here. If you were to execute `$students = $user->students()` you'd end up with a query builder object.*

Comment: thanks for the reply.. Is there some other way to access students since each student is associated with a class/grade and each grade/class is associated with a user. This may be confusing but I hope you get it.. Your answer is appreciated but just wondering if there's some other way.

Comment: @Azima You could get all the grades for a user, and then get all students associated to that grade, so 2 queries and a foreach loop